# opencv, detect outline of foreground and center photo

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, semantic-segmentation

I am curious if anyone knows a best approach for determining outline of a user's profile, i.e. isolating the foreground from background. Ideally with this info also I want to crop the photo to center on the user profile, and white out background so it's more standardized overall.

So a use case here is that individual might be standing all the way to far left; they will be posing so this will be a portrait photo. I want to isolate the user's general area somehow, and center the photo based on their profile image. I would like to achieve this using the `opencv` library in python if possible. I have worked with `opencv` before but this was for detecting background before, which is somewhat different from the task here.

So to iterate, what I'd like to achieve here is:

- center/crop the user photo as needed
- switch the background out with a standardized color - for ex. just white will do.

Again, I'm not sure if a current API supports this; I looked into Zoom API but I think I might be headed in the wrong direction. My best impression is that an image processing library like `opencv` might be the best bet for this kind of task. Appreciate any inputs or suggestions on how to achieve it.

My work so far:

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("user_photo.jpg")
crop_img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

cv2.imshow("cropped", crop_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: (1) semantic segmentation of human body, use AI (2) remove/blur background based on segmentation mask (3) crop to taste

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thanks. do you know any articles that can walk me thru this? also, just a note that I have been successful in getting the bounding coords (ex. x/y) for user profile, however not sure about best approach to blur/remove background based on this.

Comment: define "user profile". is this for passport photos or for website scraping?

Comment: So this is for informal photos, but yeah something similar to passport photos. Basically similar to a professional setting, where a person is standing against a white background, and a cameraperson takes a photo. However, this is in more of a casual setting (could also be selfies or similar) and can be in different backgrounds - for example, in a darker background and ambient lightning, and even outdoors; basically we want to standardize it so that we can remove any backgrounds, and just have the person centered on just a white background.

Comment: for background subtraction tasks in "moving" pictures aka videos: I really could suggest the following project: https://github.com/andrewssobral/bgslibrary   (this project is great because you could choose from a zoo of algos to taggle background substraction) but for single pictures it could maybe fail